# Find nodes with 3+ occurrences in a 10 minute period

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a list of nodes with a `startTime` property. I need to determine if the list contains a clump of 3 or more nodes with a `startTime` within 10 minutes of each other. I don't need to get the nodes that are in the clump, I just need a boolean indicating the existence of such a clump.

I am at a loss, everything I have tried fails so badly that it is not worth posting them.

I feel that I am missing something easy.

Comment: Fails how? Are you getting the wrong results or are your queries just taking too long to complete?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be doable.

First you'll need to collect the startTimes, order them, and collect them.

From there, you'll need to get the relevant pairings (each entry, and the entry 2 indices ahead for the end of the duration) that will comprise a group of 3, then see if the start times of that pair occur within 10 minutes of each other.

Assuming for the sake of example :Event nodes with a `startTime` property, you might use this query to get the results you want:

```
MATCH (e:Event)
WITH e
ORDER BY e.startTime ASC
WITH collect(e.startTime)[1..] as times
WITH times, range(0, size(times) - 3) as indices
RETURN any(index in indices WHERE times[index + 2] <= times[index] + duration({minutes:10}))
```